# Error al compilar "Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes"

Tags: android

Estaba ejecutando mi aplicación y de pronto ya no funciona y me salen estos  errores:

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Error:1 error; aborting

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

Este es el build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lacasadelpan.com.archivos.lacasadelpan"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Pon el código donde te genera este error, sin código es muy difícil ayudarte, aunque parece que el error indica que has intentado hacer un casting que ha fallado.

Comment: Enseñanos tus imports en gradle pls, que librerias usas.

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle

Answer (score -1):

Intenta usar `Clean` en el proyecto antes de compilar.
Si no soluciona, agrega en tu gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```